# Converting Byte results in NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I am compressing a byte array, and then converting each byte to something like this 000100111.
When doing this, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111011010"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
at logic.ColorManager.getBinary(ColorManager.java:101)
at logic.ColorManager.convertByteToColor(ColorManager.java:47)
at logic.ColorManager.writeColors(ColorManager.java:86)
at logic.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

The byte that causes the exception is: -32. 
This is my method to convert the bytes:

```
public String getBinary(byte byt) {
    try {
        int tmpNm = Integer.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString((int) byt));
        String tmpNmS = String.valueOf(tmpNm);
        while (tmpNmS.length() < 8) {
            tmpNmS = "0" + tmpNmS;
        }
        return tmpNmS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

How do I convert a negative byte to its binary equivalent? eg. 01010010

Comment: What is the point of `Integer.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString((int) byt));`?

Comment: I am converting a byte to something like 01010010